# How should I properly connect outdoor string lights to power outlet?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I got [this string light](https://www.costco.com/feit-electric-48%27-led-filament-string-light-set.product.100405061.html) from Costco and I am currently using a heavy duty outdoor extension cord to connect it temporarily.

The outdoor power outlet is around 10 ft away from where the string lights need to be plugged in.

What would be the best way to connect it permanently?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that this string light is intended for permanent use to begin with? Check its labeling...

Comment: I'd not put the string of lights straight below your guttering - water will drip down the barge board.  Instead run it under the soffit, depends on the heat output of each lamp.

Comment: I have those in a covered outdoor area and fortunately have good attic access and good access to the main panel from there, so I installed an outlet in the ceiling and used a timer to automatically turn them on and off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if you don't mind eventually (see below) drilling some of the brick's mortar in a few spots.

You'll need Wire Clips or Cable Clamps. You may also find the Copper version in the right Plumbing Aisle of a big box store to be most attractive and longest lived. If possible, paint your screws and washers (if any are used) or only use stainless steel screws and washers.

I presume you'll drape the extension cord over the gutter's downspout and run behind that to the outlet. If not, then you'll need more clips/clamps.

There are Adhesive Clips/Clamps (usually in the Seasonal Aisle) and I would start with those until you decide on final routing and looping. But fortunately, your outlet box accommodates a cord while being securely shut...so that's a great start.

And yes, I would and you can use the outlet box's screws for 2 clips/clamps...I would use both on one side. I'd suggest using the left plug and the right side's screws or the converse. To keep the extension cord fairly relaxed and happy in its quite low drop from the outlet box before the upturn toward the gutter.

If the cord is too stiff for the outlet box to close or to stay plugged-in. Then, using a bar or bracket from the Plumbing Aisle or Hardware Aisle with the 2 bottom screws may be needed for that taming.

And then, plan on coiling and mounting any extra extension cord to the eave's underside, for the cleanest look.

Comment: I was following right along until "And yes, I would and you can use the outlet box's screws for 2 clips/clamps..." from that point on, I'm really confused about what you're describing. "outlet box's screws for 2 clips/clamps..." what are those? "using a bar or bracket from" what kind of bar/bracket? What 2 screws? Sorry, I must be really slow this morning. Can you draw a picture or pick some different words?

Comment: Just the mounting screws around the box's perimeter. See the 4 of them. They should be quite secure.

Comment: Oh, use the box's mounting screws to _also_ hold clamps to hold the extension cord in place? That makes sense and saves drilling new holes in the brick. I was, obviously, quite lost... thanks!

Comment: @Iggy, Thanks. This is very helpful.